# Split an NSString in Objective-C with no delimiter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know there are several answers on splitting strings using componentsSeparatedByString:, but what if the string has no delimiter. using @"", doesn't work.

```
NSString *str = @"ABCDE";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", arr)
==> ABCDE
```

What I want is -

```
==> (A,B,C,D,E)
```

So that I can access each character.  Thanks!

Comment: try doing NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Comment: @user2277872 And why in the world would that work?

Comment: You have to iterate unichars but you also want to be careful about an possible decomposed character sequences or characters that depend on surrounding context depending in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `[string characterAtIndex:i];` in a `for` loop or
`- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange` in a loop.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
{
    unsigned int character = [string characterAtIndex:i];
    [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",character]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable technique is to use `-[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:]` with the `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` option.

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray array];
[str enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)
                        options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                     usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){
    [array addObject:substring];
}];
```